# Bluetooth/Wireless games between different TYPES of devices

Tags: bluetooth, wireless

Is it possible to create a connection between say a PSP and an IPhone, or any other app-ready bluetooth-enabled/wifi device?

I'm not too clear on the difference and capabilities of bluetooth and wifi, and when bluetooth is used in say ipod touch gaming.

If I were to use something like airplay sdk - http://www.airplaysdk.com/ - which compiles to arm, so it is the same across all target devices, theoretically they should be able to connect to eachother?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bluetooth the devices need to support the same Bluetooth profile (with sub-specialization) and opposite roles.
So PSP to iPhone connection might not be possible (without hacks)
The supported profile in Apple devices is listed here 
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3647?viewlocale=en_US
 hope it helps..